# How to append data to xml content in Android

Tags: android

I have an xml file in the following path "/res/xml/keywords.xml".
It has the following content

```
<words>
hdhsd
</words>
```

I used the following java code:

```
    OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("keywords.xml", MODE_APPEND));
    out.write("hello");
   out.close();
```

The word "hello" hasn't been appended to the file. why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are read-only and cannot be edited. Your best bet is to copy the file to the app's home folder the first time you use it, and use that copy. (In that case it is probably better to deploy the file in /assets instead of /res/xml.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that I shall use my xml file in the following path "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\D\Temp\Android\Books\Beginning Android 3\Applications\AndroidApplication2"?

Comment: I use the following code to write data in the xml file
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop\\D\\Temp\\Android\\Books\\Beginning Android 3\\Applications\\AndroidApplication2\\keywords.xml"));
Node node = doc.getElementsByTagName("words").item(0);
org.w3c.dom.Element newelmnt = doc.createElement("word");
newelmnt.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("moijjjjjjj"));
node.appendChild(newelmnt);

Comment: But IOException has been through.Where is the issue here?

Comment: I have noticed that the IOException message states the file in the following path "/C:/......" doesn't exist. Why the / before C exists?

Comment: "C:\Documents and Settings" is on your local hard drive. You can't write to your PC from your Android phone! When I said the app's home folder, I meant the folder ON YOUR PHONE that the app gets installed to. The app can create files in that folder. Check out Context.openFileOutput(). As for DocumentBuilder I've never used that class so I cannot help you there.

Comment: Thanks alot for your calrification

Answer (score 1):

To create xml file in your android application where you could read, write and update my application, use the following code

```
os=getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("keywords.xml", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
os.write("<words><word>moha</word></words>".getBytes());
os.close();
```